# Extract specific value from HTML with bs4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the value of an HTML tag. The HTML is returned in the response of a site after I make a post request to it.

The HTML snippet I want to parse looks like this:

```
<input name=\"secret\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1NTQ2NjIyMzksImFjdGlvbiI6IlwvY2FydFwvcGx1c1wvMWNlNzUtMTEzNzYzIn0=\">\n    <input name=\"product_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"156863\">\n    <input name=\"product_bs_id\"  type=\"hidden\" value=\"113763\">\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\">\n
```

I want the value with the name secret

I tried solving it like this:

```
soup=bs(req.text, 'lxml')
secret=soup.find('input',{'name':'secret'})['value']
```

Because of those Backslashes I also tried it like this:

`secret=soup.find('input',{'name':'secret'})['value']`

But I still always got the error 'NoneType not subscriptable'. Basically it didn't find it.
Any clue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more information about what `req.text` is? I think that may be your issue.

Comment: @MarkLyons req.text is the response given by a request made to gain the text to parse

Comment: Are you sure that req.text corresponds to the HTML snippet you posted? I just passed that into a string and ran your code and it extracted the value just fine. That's why I think the issue might be in req.text not being what you expect.

Comment: @MarkLyons yes that is part of the response I get, when using this as a string it works, when parsing the whole response it doesnt

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it is improperly encoded. Try `req.encoding = UTF-8` before accessing `req.text`.

Comment: @MarkLyons doesn't change anything for me

Comment: I'm not sure what else I'd suggest other than it seems like your issue is definitely that `req.text` is not the string you are expecting it to be. It would be helpful to see `req` and where it comes from, but it also sounds like it is sensitive info/difficult for others to reproduce. If you want to move this to chat I'd be happy to see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Selector to retrieve the value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''<input name=\"secret\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1NTQ2NjIyMzksImFjdGlvbiI6IlwvY2FydFwvcGx1c1wvMWNlNzUtMTEzNzYzIn0=\">\n
<input name=\"product_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"156863\">\n
<input name=\"product_bs_id\"  type=\"hidden\" value=\"113763\">\n
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\">\n    '''

soup=bs(html, 'lxml')
secret=soup.select_one('input[name^=\\secret]')
print(secret['value'])
```

Output:

```
eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1NTQ2NjIyMzksImFjdGlvbiI6IlwvY2FydFwvcGx1c1wvMWNlNzUtMTEzNzYzIn0=
```

Comment: `input[name^=\\secret]` should really be just `input[name^=secret]`. `\s` will resolve as a CSS escape `\s`, which will just be `s` so it will still work, but the escape is really not needed.